# Does Windows 7 and 10 require different user rights to start a service?

Tags: c++, service, windows-7, windows-10

I can start a Windows service from the command prompt in Windows 7 without having to run the command window as an administrator, like this:

```
sc start myservice
```

However, if I do the same thing on Windows 10, it doesn't start the service, and returns an "access denied" error. It does start fine if I start the command window as an administrator.

What I really want is to start the service from C++ code, but administrative privileges on Windows 10 are getting in my way. It seems like there are clear differences between Windows 7 & 10, but the [`OpenService()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-startservicea) documentation doesn't talk about it at all!

Now, its a dumb question to ask if we can work around this security issue, but is it possible to work around it by perhaps setting certain security attributes?

In the code below, `OpenService()` fails with error code 5, since it is asking for `SERVICE_START` rights:

```
void DoStartSvc()
{
    SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS ssStatus;
    DWORD dwOldCheckPoint;
    DWORD dwStartTickCount;
    DWORD dwWaitTime;
    DWORD dwBytesNeeded;

    TCHAR szSvcName[256] = _T("MyService");
    SC_HANDLE schSCManager;
    SC_HANDLE schService;

    // Get a handle to the SCM database. 

    schSCManager = OpenSCManager(
        NULL,                    // local computer
        NULL,                    // servicesActive database 
        SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);  // use SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS for full access rights 

    if (NULL == schSCManager)
    {
        printf("OpenSCManager failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    // Get a handle to the service.

    schService = OpenService(
        schSCManager,         // SCM database 
        szSvcName,            // name of service 
        SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS | SERVICE_START );  // use SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS for full access 

    if (schService == NULL)
    {
        printf("OpenService failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
        return;
    }

    // Check the status in case the service is not stopped. 

    if (!QueryServiceStatusEx(
        schService,                     // handle to service 
        SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO,         // information level
        (LPBYTE)& ssStatus,             // address of structure
        sizeof(SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS), // size of structure
        &dwBytesNeeded))              // size needed if buffer is too small
    {
        printf("QueryServiceStatusEx failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        CloseServiceHandle(schService);
        CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
        return;
    }

    // Check if the service is already running. It would be possible 
    // to stop the service here, but for simplicity this example just returns. 

    if (ssStatus.dwCurrentState != SERVICE_STOPPED && ssStatus.dwCurrentState != SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
    {
        printf("Cannot start the service because it is already running\n");
        CloseServiceHandle(schService);
        CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
        return;
    }

    // Save the tick count and initial checkpoint.

    dwStartTickCount = GetTickCount();
    dwOldCheckPoint = ssStatus.dwCheckPoint;

    // Wait for the service to stop before attempting to start it.

    while (ssStatus.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
    {
        // Do not wait longer than the wait hint. A good interval is 
        // one-tenth of the wait hint but not less than 1 second  
        // and not more than 10 seconds. 

        dwWaitTime = ssStatus.dwWaitHint / 10;

        if (dwWaitTime < 1000)
            dwWaitTime = 1000;
        else if (dwWaitTime > 10000)
            dwWaitTime = 10000;

        Sleep(dwWaitTime);

        // Check the status until the service is no longer stop pending. 

        if (!QueryServiceStatusEx(
            schService,                     // handle to service 
            SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO,         // information level
            (LPBYTE)&ssStatus,             // address of structure
            sizeof(SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS), // size of structure
            &dwBytesNeeded))              // size needed if buffer is too small
        {
            printf("QueryServiceStatusEx failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
            CloseServiceHandle(schService);
            CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
            return;
        }

        if (ssStatus.dwCheckPoint > dwOldCheckPoint)
        {
            // Continue to wait and check.

            dwStartTickCount = GetTickCount();
            dwOldCheckPoint = ssStatus.dwCheckPoint;
        }
        else
        {
            if (GetTickCount() - dwStartTickCount > ssStatus.dwWaitHint)
            {
                printf("Timeout waiting for service to stop\n");
                CloseServiceHandle(schService);
                CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    // Attempt to start the service.

    if (!StartService(
        schService,  // handle to service 
        0,           // number of arguments 
        NULL))      // no arguments 
    {
        printf("StartService failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        CloseServiceHandle(schService);
        CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
        return;
    }
    else printf("Service start pending...\n");

    // Check the status until the service is no longer start pending. 

    if (!QueryServiceStatusEx(
        schService,                     // handle to service 
        SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO,         // info level
        (LPBYTE)&ssStatus,             // address of structure
        sizeof(SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS), // size of structure
        &dwBytesNeeded))              // if buffer too small
    {
        printf("QueryServiceStatusEx failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        CloseServiceHandle(schService);
        CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
        return;
    }

    // Save the tick count and initial checkpoint.

    dwStartTickCount = GetTickCount();
    dwOldCheckPoint = ssStatus.dwCheckPoint;

    while (ssStatus.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_START_PENDING)
    {
        // Do not wait longer than the wait hint. A good interval is 
        // one-tenth the wait hint, but no less than 1 second and no 
        // more than 10 seconds. 

        dwWaitTime = ssStatus.dwWaitHint / 10;

        if (dwWaitTime < 1000)
            dwWaitTime = 1000;
        else if (dwWaitTime > 10000)
            dwWaitTime = 10000;

        Sleep(dwWaitTime);

        // Check the status again. 

        if (!QueryServiceStatusEx(
            schService,             // handle to service 
            SC_STATUS_PROCESS_INFO, // info level
            (LPBYTE)&ssStatus,             // address of structure
            sizeof(SERVICE_STATUS_PROCESS), // size of structure
            &dwBytesNeeded))              // if buffer too small
        {
            printf("QueryServiceStatusEx failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
            break;
        }

        if (ssStatus.dwCheckPoint > dwOldCheckPoint)
        {
            // Continue to wait and check.

            dwStartTickCount = GetTickCount();
            dwOldCheckPoint = ssStatus.dwCheckPoint;
        }
        else
        {
            if (GetTickCount() - dwStartTickCount > ssStatus.dwWaitHint)
            {
                // No progress made within the wait hint.
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Determine whether the service is running.

    if (ssStatus.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_RUNNING)
    {
        printf("Service started successfully.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Service not started. \n");
        printf("  Current State: %d\n", ssStatus.dwCurrentState);
        printf("  Exit Code: %d\n", ssStatus.dwWin32ExitCode);
        printf("  Check Point: %d\n", ssStatus.dwCheckPoint);
        printf("  Wait Hint: %d\n", ssStatus.dwWaitHint);
    }

    CloseServiceHandle(schService);
    CloseServiceHandle(schSCManager);
}
```

Comment: Seems like two questions, the main one being about Windows administration rather than C++.

Comment: @NeilButterworth It is a question about starting service from C++ as a standard user.

Comment: By default, only an admin can start/stop a service, that has always been true. On Windows 7, `sc.exe` is manifested as `requestedExecutionLevel=asInvoker`, the only way it can start a service when run as a non-admin is if that user has rights to start a service. Maybe your Win7 system has lowered its security settings to allow a non-admin to start/stop a service, but that is certainly not the norm, and you should not rely on that. On most systems, you need to run your code with elevated admin rights in order to (un)install and start/stop a service. You should have been doing that all along.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks that helps because this was part of the confusion that Windows 7 and 8 are suppose to be same in this regard so why it just works on Win7 is part of the puzzle but righ, seems like user has extra rights there.

Comment: Please include the discretionary-access SDDL strings for the service in both the Windows 7 and 10 systems, as output by `sc.exe sdshow [service name]`, e.g. "D:(A;;...;;;SY)(A;;...;;;BA)(A;;...;;;IU)(A;;...;;;SU)". By default, Administrators (BA) should have generic-all access (0xF01FF). LocalSystem (SY) should have generic-read and generic-execute access (0x201FD). Interactive and service users (IU, SU) should have generic-read and also user-defined control access (0x2018D), but not any other execute access (i.e. start, stop, pause).